# HTML 5 semantics

Tags: html, semantics

I've been reading for a while now about the correct semantics of HTML 5 and am not sure about some things still.

My website outputs from the database like so:

- Title (currently using `<h2>`)
- Descrption (currently using `<p>`)
- Image (currently using `<img>` and no wrapper element)
- Open/Close (currently using `<p>`)
- Services

  - cider (yes/no)
  - wine (yes/no)
  - draft (yes/no)

I am very confused with this:

should each result `<div>` now be within a `<section>` element, so a page would output 10 results all within a `<section>`,  or would it be html5 semantically correct using 1 `<section>` to contain the results as it is a results `<section>` and each result is held within a `<div id="unique_number">` ???

thanks

Answer (score 3):

A section is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading.
I would use a section foreach result in your case.

Example:

```
<section>
 <header><h1>Trollinger</h1></header>
  <p>Red, Delicious</p>
  <img/>
 <p>open</p>
 <ul>
  <li>cider</li>
  <li>wine</li>
  <li>draft</li>
 </ul>
</section>
```

Reference: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-section-element

Comment: only difference I'd suggest is to nest a heading tag (h1-h6) in the `<header>`... `<header><h3>[Title]</h3></header>` (assuming the page has a h1/h2 already above the result set)

Comment: @mdm You should use a H1 heading because heading should be independent for each section. (but forget the heading, thanks!)

Comment: I think that's arguable, from a page level perspective the `h1` would go to only the page heading like `Search Results for 'XXXX'`.  Then each result heading would be less significant (such as an `h2` or `h3` to represent a lower level heading title.  But I can see the argument for giving each result item an `h1`

Comment: I guess too I was picturing this as a result set, maybe it's just one item, so `h1` makes more sense

Comment: @mdm Look at the specs: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements - These elements represent headings for their sections.

Comment: that is interesting, I guess I'm still thinking in pre-html5 practices.

Comment: it will output 10 results for example, I am currenting using h3 within a section element as h1 is the website logo which is contained within the header element : <header><h1>mainlogo</h1></header>

Have any of you guys used hgroup yet or  details elements yet?

Comment: thanks for the input, i find the semantic element talk interesting and varied

Answer (score 1):

The title of a web page should be set in the `<title>Title</title>` (located in `<head>`) as well as on the page (in the `body`) with an `<h1>`. This is both semantic and SEO friendly.

The "description", if it stands alone, could be a `<span>.` If it's part of some other text, a paragraph is good, but generally paragraphs don't stand alone, so use a span if that's the case.
Image: it depends. If this image is purely for styling - perhaps a swirl in the backround or a gradient - it should be set as the background-image of an element in CSS. If it's actual content (like a logo, photo), then use the `<img>` tag. 
I'm going to guess "Open" and "Close" are interactive elements, links, or buttons. If so, use a `<button>` or an anchor: `<a>`, not a paragraph. If these are headings, use one of the heading tags. Since you've used `<h1>`, then use `<h2>` (unless it's not a very important heading)

As to your "Results", [according to the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element),

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading.

Additionally,

> The section element is not a generic container element. When an
>   element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for
>   scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
>   general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
>   element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
>   outline.

So in your case, a `<div>` for search results is probably fine.

Comment: i forgot about the SPAN element, a few years ago I used to use the SPAN element for singular line or inline text, for example: a telephone number or the abbr. Tel. Is span still being used in HTML5 for the same purposes, as for OPEN and CLOSE they refer to the time of opening and closing, which will display the 24hour time below the title, example:

OPEN - CLOSE

13:00 - 00:00

Comment: thanks for the input, i find the semantic element talk interesting and varied

Comment: thanks , i am currently reading the HTML 5 spec, i haven't built a website in over 2 years and am wondering if you guys actually still use this practise when using HTML5. From what I have read, nothing appears to have changed in regards to the span element, i personally will use this in my case as span with a class is more appropriate than the P element with a class.

Comment: @Renai yep, spans are used for that often. That's a good choice; though a heading (h1-h6) might work too.